# EXTJS & Java Struts export csv file

Tags: java, csv, extjs, export

I want to make a csv file and let the user download it by clicking at a button.
There is a form to search users (with some search fields) and the button search : this is to search users and display them in the grid.
After the form, there is a link "export to csv", this have to take the form fields values, pass it to Java (struts), then Java construct a csv file (not the same as the grid, it is more complex, many values from many tables) and return it to extjs, after that, i want to give it to the user, let him download it. The response.responseText contains the good csv to export but it is too big to do an *encodeURI* :(

I am not able to propose to download the file. Someone has any idea? :(

Here is the source code i did for now :

```
var params = Ext.getCmp("userSearchEngine").getForm().getValues(false);
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : cmts.server + 'exportToCSV.do',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/csv'},                    
    params : params,

    success: function ( response, request ) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(response.responseText);
    },

    failure: function ( response, request ) {
        console.log('FAIL !');
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT : the Java part writes in the outputstream of the response

EDIT 2 : Due to some limitations, i cannot create files on the server side

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

1. One Ext.form.FieldContainer as a link.
2. Server side (in my case PHP) generates the file in 'tmp' directory.
3. Server side returns valid JSON, which contains the name of the generated file.
4. AJAX request changes the link of Ext.form.FieldContainer.

Partial example:

**ExtJS part - fieldcontainer:**

```
{
id: 'generatecsv',
xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
width: 100,
layout: 'vbox',
items: [
    {xtype: 'displayfield', value: ''},
    {
    id: 'dds19_link_disk',
    xtype: 'box', 
    autoEl: {
        html: '<a href="./tmp/" target="_blank">Download CSV</a>',
        width: 100
    } 
    }
]   
}
```

**ExtJS - AJAX request:**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: './src/xxxxx.php',
    jsonData: Ext.JSON.encode({
    }),
    success: function(response){
        var r = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        if (r.success == true) { 
            Ext.getCmp('generatecsv').el.update('<a href="./tmp/'+r.filename+'" target="_blank">ZIP архив</a>');
        } else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', r.errmsg);       
        };
    },
    failure: function(response){
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Error.');       
    }
});
```

**Valid JSON from server:**

```
{
"success": true,
"filename": "generated_file_name.csv"
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Due to some limitations, i cannot create files on the server side :( Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Ryoku May be it is possible to return the file content with JSON, as array, row per row and then iterate this array in Ext.Ajax.Request. But I haven't tested it :(. And this is not a download approach.

Comment: - use serverside controller where url mapping should be your filename ex: "y/generated_file_name.csv?parameters" 
In server side write your csv content to response.getOutputStream()
like: IOUtils.copy(theCSVInputStream, response.getOutputStream());

Comment: if i do something like this : window.location.replace(cmts.server + 'exportToCSV.do'), it download the csv file (without create file) but i cannot pass the form like this :( Maybe this information can help you to help me? This means, access to an url which return the response I get in my ajax success function whould launch the download of the file (because of the headers http i guess)

Comment: You can not download a file through ajax. It is forbidden by browser security. You can use Data URLs but you also mentioned size limit. However, keep in mind that data url size limits are quite  large.

You can use a Downloadify library for such ops. But as I sad even such libs can not use ajax

Answer (score 0):

for downloadfile you can try form submit

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  standardSubmit : true,
  url : url,
  method : 'POST' // OR 'GET'
});

form.submit({
  target : '_blank',
  params : {

  }
});
```

and in serverside - java :

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName)
        + ".csv");

IOUtils.copy(theCSVInputStream, response.getOutputStream())
```